# Advanced Web Browsing: hitting next with keyboard (single keystroke)

Tags: browser, keyboard-shortcuts, javascript, hotkeys

I have a website for class that is literally 1000's of pages long, with a next button at the bottom like this:

Prev 1 2 3 4 Next

With the following code, if that helps:

```
<a href="javascript:gotoModuleObjective(1,1,34,17, 1, 0);">Prev</a> </td>
<td align="center" width="10"> <font color="CC0000">1</font> </td>
<td align="center" width="10"> <a href="javascript:gotoModuleObjective(1,24,33,2,1,0);">2</a> </td>
<td align="center" width="10"> <a href="javascript:gotoModuleObjective(1,24,33,3,1,0);">3</a> </td>
<td align="center" width="10"> <a href="javascript:gotoModuleObjective(1,24,33,4,1,0);">4</a> </td>
<td align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;" width="30"> <a href="javascript:gotoModuleObjective(1, 24,33,2, 1, 0);">Next</a> </td>
```

The numbers change depending on where you are.

I would like to be able to, from the keyboard, hit the next button.  I am using windows, but can switch to any browser, if this is only possible is a given browser.  If this can be done with **just one keystroke** that would be wonderful.  Like just hitting the forward arrow would automatically bring click the button called next and bring me to the next page.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that [Opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/) has a good "fast forward" function (which tries to guess the next link), but I don't know how it would do with your particular site, especially if talking about javascript links, and not regular ones.

So I can only propose you to try it on your site (fast forward can be activated with gestures to the right, or Space repeatedly, until reaching the end of the page, if I remember good). Try with any Google search to be sure that you are using it good, it works on them easily.

Comment: I'm not sure if Opera is *guessing* the link? I always *assumed* it was relying on `rel="next"` from the HTML -- just like Super User et al specify. (See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39053/feature-request-use-ctrl-rightarrow-ctrl-leftarrow-to-navigate-between-pages/39058#39058)

Comment: @Dan, if it indeed needs `rel="next"` then using Greasemonkey you could indeed add that to the links, if you can somehow specify what links it applies to. (Or ask the site owner to do it for you?)

Comment: @Arjan: It uses said `<link>` but links that contain `>>` or `<<` in their text will work too, iirc. It's been some years since I've used that, though, so not sure anymore.

Comment: @Arjan - My knowledge in this field is very thin, so to me, as a simple "Opera user", it is some magic guessing ;) If someone has more information on it, I would be glad to know, though.

Comment: If it doesn't find a `rel=next`, Opera checks for a number of text strings to "guess" the next link. Exactly what strings to look for can be customized in `fastforward.ini` in your Opera directory.

Answer (score 2):

[AutoPager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4925) for Firefox

> automatically loads next pages when you reach the end of a page. It works on a ton of sites,Google,Yahoo..
>   It works well with most other add-ons adblock plus, WOT and most of the greasemonkey scripts...
>   [It] automatically loads the next page of a site inline when you reach the end of the current page for infinite scrolling of content.

[NextPage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=page&cat=all) for Firefox

> rebinds SPC key so that it scroll page when there is more on the page, it go to next page when at the bottom of a page. You can also use n key anytime directly to go to next page.
>
> Here is a list of keys that get
>   rebinded: SPC scroll up/next page. n
>   next page. p history back. 2 next page. 1
>   history back. Alt-n next page (useful
>   when cursor is at location bar or
>   search box)

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the HTML, try setting an access key for the next button. [This article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/accesskeys/) discusses some issues with this underused accessibility feature.

Other than that try a Greasemonkey script.

Comment: I don't have a control over the HTML. Your suggesting making a custom Greasemonkey script? That is perhaps a bit out of my ability, can you give me a few pointers to get started?  I guess at this point I might need to take this to stackoverflow.

Comment: Greasemonkey is a custom Firefox addon that lets you write javascript to modify the behavior of a web page. You could write a script to add the access key to that "next" link.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748

Comment: @Dan, if you need help with Greasemonkey then please provide the URL of the website you're trying to access?

Comment: Definitely sounds like a good use for a Greasemonkey script. You may be able to use an existing one too... like this: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/31729

Comment: @Greg, nice find! Sounds like an answer by itself to me!